# Flask unit test not receiving data specified

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Weird behavior in Flask unit testing under Python 3.
In the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/testing/#test-adding-messages), it says that you can add data to a test request using the `data` parameter.

However, whenever I utilize this as in the example below, `request.data` always comes back empty.  Further proof of this is that when I inspect the `__dict__` attribute of the `request` object the `CONTENT_LENGTH == 0`.

```
import base64

import pytest
import flask

from my_program import api


@pytest.fixture
def test_api():
    return api.app.test_client()


def test_patch_accounts_without_payload(test_api):
    response = test_api.patch(
        '/accounts/{}/'.format(test_settings['accountEntry']['uid']),
        data={"first": "Mickey", "last": "Mouse"},
        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

Here is the code that handles this route (it's just a stub at the moment):

```
@app.route('/accounts/<identifier>/', methods=['PATCH'])
def patch_account_entry(identifier):
    app.logger.debug(request.__dict__)
    app.logger.debug(request.content_type)
    app.logger.debug(request.get_json())

    response = jsonify({"message": "Blah", "status": 400})
    response.status_code = 400
    return response
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Where is `test_api.patch` come from? Do you mean `test_api.post`?

Comment: @skyline75489, `patch` is just another HTTP method call available on the test client.  It could be `post` as well.

Comment: Can you post the handler code as well?

Comment: @skyline75489 I'm not sure what you are referring to as the handler code. Do you mean the Flask code that implements the `test_client()`?

Comment: No. I mean the flask code that handles `/accounts/{}/`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79452/discussion-between-eikonomega-and-skyline75489).